# C# combining variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am in a C# class and have been stuck all day trying to get this, I have tried it a bunch of different ways.

We are working with session state I have 5 fields that I need to record to session state, validate to make sure they are not empty, if they are change the filed to yellow and then display a message to a label stating what filed or fields where left blank and they they cannot be blank.

I have it working except for the message part.
I tried using the same variable `errMsg` in all 5 if statements trying to string them together using the + sign but that would not work.
Now I have defined a variable for each of the 5 if statements and then towards the bottom combining them to display the message for each filed left blank, and now I just get error:

> Use of unassigned local variable

Here is my code I have been working on this most of the day I know it is basic but not sure how to get these individual messages to display to the label if there fields are blank.

Thanks.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Assigning our form data so session state values
    Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
    Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
    Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;

    string errFN;
    string errLN;
    string errPD;
    string errSD;
    string errED;

    //Validation of each session state making sure they are not empty 
    //(probably a better way to do this but what I came up with)
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text))
    {
        txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errFN = Convert.ToString("First Name may not be empty.");
    }
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text))
    {
        txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errLN = Convert.ToString("Last Name may not be empty.");
    }
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPayRate.Text))
    {
        txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errPD = Convert.ToString("Pay Rate may not be empty.");
    }
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStartDate.Text))
    {
        txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errSD = Convert.ToString("Start Date may not be empty.");
    }
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEndDate.Text))
    {
        txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errED = Convert.ToString("End Date may not be empty.");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text) ||     string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPayRate.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStartDate.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEndDate.Text))
    {
        lblError.Text = errFN + errLN + errPD + errSD + errED;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: look up the errorprovider,it will help you

Comment: have a look at the `StringBuilder` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Use of unassigned local variable` is because of here

```
lblError.Text = errFN + errLN + errPD + errSD + errED;
```

you use an unsigned variable if there's no error.

you should initialize your variables like this

```
string errFN = System.String.Empty;
string errLN = System.String.Empty;
string errPD = System.String.Empty;
```

or

```
string errSD = "";
string errED = "";
```

So if there's no error, the variable will be initialized and empty

Comment: Awesome thanks a ton I new it had to be something stupid easy that worked.

Comment: btw you had the same problem when you were doing += . You could use only 1 variable but you have to initialize it before

Answer (score 0):

1.you need to `Trim` the values before comparing for `Empty` Check.

sometimes whitespaces (which will not be visible on `TextBox`) does not match with `Empty` string

2.you need to always `assign` the `local` variables.

Try this Code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Assigning our form data so session state values
    Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
    Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
    Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;

    string errFN="";
    string errLN="";
    string errPD="";
    string errSD="";
    string errED="";

    //Validation of each session state making sure they are not empty 
    //(probably a better way to do this but what I came up with)
    if(txtFirstName.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errFN = Convert.ToString("First Name may not be empty.");
    }
    if(txtLastName.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errLN = Convert.ToString("Last Name may not be empty.");
    }
    if(txtPayRate.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errPD = Convert.ToString("Pay Rate may not be empty.");
    }
    if(txtStartDate.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errSD = Convert.ToString("Start Date may not be empty.");
    }
    if(txtEndDate.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        errED = Convert.ToString("End Date may not be empty.");
    }

    if (txtFirstName.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals("") ||     txtLastName.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals("") || txtPayRate.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals("") ||
        txtStartDate.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals("") || txtEndDate.Text.ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        lblError.Text = errFN + errLN + errPD + errSD + errED;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the tips, I am going to go read on the first point you made to learn more about that, but that makes sense from what I think it means..  White space could pass the empty text check, so the Trim will cut that out so it doesn't pass the check even though it looks empty.